# When exporting .Apk in the android manifest its does not install on other phones, when getting from Bin folder it does install?

Tags: android, installation, apk

Basically I made an app and exported the `.apk` (from the Android Manifest exporting section) so I could try it on my dad's phone.

I tried to install it on my dad and sister's phone and it gave `"application not installed"` however if I get the `.apk` from the Bin folder it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

If I want to install the app on another phone what would I use to get the `.apk`?
Is getting the `.apk` from bin safe as it does not have certificate?

Comment: All apks that you want to install (not necessarily share) need to be signed, either with the debug keystore (your /bin) or your own keystore.

Comment: Please don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely a problem with the certificate. Try making a new certificate, keystore, and alias, then generate the .apk again. Make sure that no previous instance of the app is on the phone when you try to install this new version or the mismatch of signatures will cause the installation to fail.

Also, was there a previous version of the app installed on their phones already? The signature mismatch may occur due to the use of both signed and unsigned(in reality the .apk is singed, but it is done automatically by the system) .apks